# Как отметить в select то что было выбрано?

Tags: angular, angular10

Есть select, использую что бы выбрать в какой валюте будет продаваться товар. Но если я захочу отредактировать товар и мне нужно редактировать currency , я хочу что б когда я розгорнул selector то там была отмечена та валюта которую я выбирал при создании товара. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

```
<mat-form-field>
     <mat-label class="">Currency</mat-label>
     <mat-select formControlName="currency" multiple>
           <mat-option *ngFor="let currency of keysCurrency" [value]="currency">
                 {{currencyType[currency]}}
           </mat-option>
     </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Из документации](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) надо использовать поле `[(value)]` (`<mat-select [(value)]="selected">`)

html:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Select an option</mat-label>
  <mat-select [(value)]="selected"> 
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option1">Option 1</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option2">Option 2</mat-option>
    <mat-option value="option3">Option 3</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Select with 2-way value binding */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-value-binding-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-value-binding-example.html',
})
export class SelectValueBindingExample {
  selected = 'option2';
}
```

Comment: @ Alexander Chernin  Спасибо, но что то не сработало. Пробую как то так но что то тоже не хочет работать
```this.updatePrintingEditionForm.controls['currency'].patchValue(this.printingEdition?.currency);```

Comment: @Dmitriy что не сработало?

Comment: ```this.updatePrintingEditionForm.controls['currency'].patchValue(this.printingEdition?.currency); ``` Это сработало только нужно было убрать из селектора multiple. Спасибо